# In angular how to open new tab from component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have simple angular application with two component. I want to open one component in new tab.

Here is my application.

In my AppComponent.html file there is a button. when I click on this button I want to open
MapComponent.html file in another tab. in this case I don't want to move AppComponent button into
MapComponent.html file. `openMapInNewTab(address: string)` I want to pass address to the MapComponent.html file and want to show google map according to the given address. At the top of the
google map I want to add user guide to how to get lat lng from map. that's why I want to open map in new component before I want to keep my height  and width 200px. how can I achive this. I have tried add route and many ways. but i couldn't able to do it.

**AppComponent.ts file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'routeApp';

  constructor(private router: Router) {}

  openMapInNewTab(address: string) {    
  }
}
```

**AppComponent.html file**

```
<button (click)="openMapInNewTab()">Open Map</button>
```

**MapComponent.ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-map',
  templateUrl: './map.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./map.component.css']
})
export class MapComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
  }   
}
```

**MapComponent.html file**

```
<p>map works!</p>
```

**AppRoutingModule file**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { MapComponent } from './map/map.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'map', component: MapComponent}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: not sure what you mean by "another tab". do you mean a second browser tab? or some kind of tab within your app? If it's a tab in your app, you have to build the tab yourself as part of your html. maybe show more of what you are trying to do.

Comment: Have a link `a` tag with `target="_blank"`. But Angular is a single page application so it'll be a new instance of the app. Everything it needs will need to be included in the url and the app will need to parse and redirect based off the url

Comment: yes in second browser tab i want to open it

Comment: angular is a single page application, so if you want to open things in another browser tab, then you would no longer be in your app, so I don't think that's what you really want to do.

Answer (score 1):

its hard to tell what you are trying to do. couple of things to think about:

1. Your html openMapInNewTab method doesn't match you ts openMapInNewTab method. the html passes nothing but the typescript is expecting a string.
2. not sure you know what you are trying to do. if you want to go from your current component to map, then user [routerLink], but if you are trying to show your map component as part of your current page, then just include this tag in your html:

   `<app-map></app-map>`

or maybe you want to go to another tab in your browser? then use an anchor with target="_blank"

Comment: yes I want to go to another tab. here from html page I am passing address as a parament in openMapInNewTab(address). like this. according to this address I want to open google map in new browser tab. map hight and width should be 200px. at the top of the map i want to add some text. do you have any idea how to do it

Comment: if you are going to a new browser tab, then you are no longer in your angular app. so just do `<a href="{{googleAddress}}" target="_blank">click here</a>`